# trigger Too many SOQL queries: 101 error

Tags: trigger, soql

I am running the below trigger and it works for a handful of records when the record set becomes larger(86 records) I get the error ":System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101"  I tried to research and change some of the code to bulkify but I am still receiving same error, would anyone know how I can fix?

```
trigger NoteDocIssueTrigger on Note__c (before insert) {

    Date anNewNoteDate  = null;

    String NoteType='Issues';

    Set<Id> anNewcl_Id = new Set<Id>();

    for (Note__c an :Trigger.new) {
        anNewcl_Id.add(an.Cl__c);

        an.Latest_Issue_Note__c = true;  

        anNewNoteDate = an.Note_Date__c;    

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //if existing note_date > incoming, post the note but no need to update the field Latest_Issue_Note__c to true
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        List<Note__c> anCheckNoteDtList = [Select Id, Cl__c, Note_Type__c, Note_Date__c from Note__c  
                                         where Cl__c in :anNewcl_Id 
                                         and Note_Type__c = :NoteType
                                         and Note_Date__c > :anNewNoteDate ];

        if(anCheckNoteDtList.size() > 0) {
           an.Latest_Issue_Note__c = false;
           System.debug('Nothing to do');
        } 
        else {

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //find any records where the Latest_Issue_Note has been checked for the cl__c
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            List<Note__c> anIssueList = [Select Id, Cl__c, Note_Type__c, Note_Date__c from Note__c  
                                             where Cl__c in :anNewcl_Id 
                                             and Note_Type__c = :NoteType
                                             and Latest_Issue_Note__c = true];

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //Clear previous Latest_Issue_Note__c values 
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            if(anIssueList.size() > 0) {
                for (Note__c anRecords : anIssueList) {
                     anRecords.Latest_Issue_Note__c = false;
                }
                update anIssueList;
            }


        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Do not put a query in a loop.

Comment: Your code is not bulkified at all. You are running at least one and in some cases two SOQL queries for every object in the trigger set. You'll need to run a single, broader query OUTSIDE the loop and then check each incoming Note__c without running another query.

Answer (score 1):

Like has been mentioned in the comments already, the code you've provided is not builkified.

In most cases, bulkification is a slightly shorter way to say "Make sure there are no queries or DML statements inside of loops".

The general pattern most people will suggest for bulkified triggers has 3 main steps:

1. Iterate over trigger.new, and gather Ids and other values that you need to perform a query
2. Perform your main query in a soql-for loop, and do your main work
3. After you've completed all of your processing, perform DML (if required)

As a simple code example

```java
Trigger X on Account(after update){
    // Step 1, gather Ids
    // Generally, you'll use a List or a Set to store these so we can easily use them
    //   in a query later.
    // My preference is to use a set
    Set<Id> acctIds = new Set<Id>();

    // Now, we gather Ids
    // This particular example could be done without a loop (acctsIds = trigger.newMap.keySet();)
    //   but this is useful for illustration
    for(Account acct :Trigger.new){
        acctIds.add(acct.Id);
    }

    // Step 2: main query in a soql-for-loop
    // First thing, declare a collection to hold the results of the work that we want to do
    //   (so we can later use DML on the entire result set at once.
    // Again, this is a contrived example. There are better ways to do what I'm doing
    //   in this example (like a rollup summary field, or failing that, a before update trigger)
    List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

    // Using a query to generate the input for the loop like this is called a
    //   "soql for loop"
    // Salesforce generally recommends this approach, as it allows Salesforce to perform
    //   some optimizations and use resources more efficiently
    for(AggregateResult ar :[SELECT AccountId, SUM(Amount) oppTotal FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN :acctIds GROUP BY AccountId]){
        accountsToUpdate.add(new Account(
            Id = (Id)ar.get('AccountId'),
            Opp_Total__c = ar.get('oppTotal') == null ? (Decimal)ar.get('oppTotal') : 0
        ));
    }

    // Step 3: DML after done with the main body of work
    // DML needs to be kept out of loops as well (we also only have 100 DML statements
    //   we can make in a single transaction)
    update accountsToUpdate;
}
```

Applying this to your trigger is, unfortunately, not quite that simple.

Removing queries from loops is easy when you can use the same set of information to filter all of your target records (an Id value, records created after a single date, records with a number field less than some amount, etc...).

What you have, on the other hand, is a query where you want to filter on a different date for each record. Queries like this are hard(er) to pull out of a loop. In most cases, it is possible, but requires that you split your filtering between SOQL and Apex.

Before continuing, I should note that I find your existing code a bit confusing. I can't figure out what the purpose is in re-querying the same `Note__c` records is subsequent iterations of your loop. To me, this looks like a *semantic* error (i.e. the code compiles, but it won't do what you intended it to). What follows is my best guess at what you might actually want to do.

With that out of our way, let's look at how we can pull your first query out of the loop.

```java
// The few lines of code that you have above this point are unchanged

// Declaring this set is the same as what you're doing now.
// I'm just changing the name so it's easier for me to work with it
Set<Id> clSet = new Set<Id>();

// This is the first deviation
// The first for loop over trigger.new should only gather data required for the query
for(Note__c myNote :Trigger.new) {
    clSet.add(myNote.cl__c);
}

// Now, the SOQL for-loop
// We can do part of the filtering here
for(Note__c myNote :[SELECT Id, Cl__c, Note_Type__c, Note_Date__c 
                     FROM Note__c  
                     Where Cl__c IN :clSet AND Note_Type__c = :NoteType]){
}
```

Well...that's a start, but we're missing the filter on the `Note_Date__c` field. That's pulled from the records in `Trigger.new` in your original trigger, but with the information you've provided, I can't be sure that this first query actually includes the records in `Trigger.new`.

So we need dates, and probably can't depend on the query to pull the records we need to obtain those dates. What do we do?

The answer is that we need to somehow gather this information prior to running the first query. Lucky for us, we are already looping over `Trigger.new`. We can just gather this information in that loop as well!

```java
Set<Id> clSet = new Set<Id>();

// In my mind, it makes sense to store Note_Date__c in a map
// The benefit to this is that if cl__c is re-used, we can pick whether we want
//   to use the newest or oldest date.
Map<Id, Date> clToDateMap = new Map<Id, Date>();

for(Note__c myNote :Trigger.new) {
    clSet.add(myNote.cl__c);

    if(!clToDateMap.containsKey(myNote.cl__c)){
        // First time seeing this cl__c value, just put the note date into the map
        clToDateMap.put(myNote.cl__c, myNote.Note_Date__c);
    }else{
        // on subsequent times seeing cl__c, we need to choose which date to keep
        if(clToDateMap.get(myNote.cl__c) < myNote.Note_Date__c){
            // In this case, when the current note date is newer than the existing
            //   one in the map, we overwrite the older date with the newer one
            clToDateMap.put(myNote.cl__c, myNote.Note_Date__c);
        }
    }
}

// We'll probably need a collection to hold records that match all of our filters
//  (both SOQL and Apex)
List<Note__c> filteredNotes = new List<Note__c>();
for(Note__c myNote :[SELECT Id, Cl__c, Note_Type__c, Note_Date__c 
                     FROM Note__c  
                     Where Cl__c IN :clSet AND Note_Type__c = :NoteType]){

    // Now we can do the last part of the filtering
    // Notice how the general form of this if statement reflects the original 
    //   filter that you had in your query
    if(myNote.Note_Date__c > clToDateMap.get(myNote.cl__c)){
        filteredNotes.add(myNote);
    }
}
```

So that pulls your first query outside of the loop. The second query should be easier (since none of the filters in your WHERE clause require different data for each record), but I'm not convinced that you need it at all.

In the end, I'm not sure if you'll be able to use the code of yours that I modified. You may be better served by asking another question stating exactly what you're trying to do (update which note(s) are marked as being the "latest issue"), but with more details (and your existing trigger), and asking for help in determining which approach to take to accomplish your goal.

For example, a good detail to include would be what the purpose of `Cl__c` is. The name alone doesn't give any clues as to what it might do. Does it point to another `Note__c` record? Does it point to some other record?

That said, there should still be some value in this answer, as it goes over how to pull slightly more difficult queries out of loops.

Comment: Thank you very much for spending time on this and explaining the steps! I will try to revise what I have and add more detail next time.